# How to manage the smoke appearance in blender

Tags: smoke-simulation

How we can change the option of the smoke modifire to create the smoke that want, for example I need a matches fire so how I can alter the options to provide such fire. So it have fire look like at bottom low Alpha blue and the n at midden dark orange so how i can develop such a fire. I mean, according to which factor we can simulate all kind of smoke and fire. Please suggest me some tips some tutorial maybe some books.

Comment: The smoke "appearance" is controlled by options of the objects responsible for smoke - [smoke flow](https://www.blender.org/manual/ru/physics/smoke/types/flow_object.html) and [smoke domain](https://www.blender.org/manual/ru/physics/smoke/types/domain.html). Options differ and control different things, and everything depends on what do you want. As your question is stated now it's too broad.

Answer (score -2):

Well you can watch a tutorial (like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-zK7Bu8cAI) in youtube.I think it also covers what you are asking.

Comment: LInk only answers are discourage as if the link goes down then so does this answer. Please include some of the steps within the answer body itself.